# Requiring a gem inside a gem's rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, bundler

I'm using jeweler to create a gem for Rails 3. The gem contains a rake task and one of the things it does is wiping the DB, so I'm using 'database_cleaner'.

I'm specifying the gem dependency inside the gem's Gemfile

```
gem 'database_cleaner'
```

And in the Rakefile

```
Jeweler::Tasks.new do |gem|
  ...
  gem.add_dependency 'database_cleaner'
end
```

Then inside lib I've created the files my_gem.rb and tasks.rake. As follows, my_gem.rb:

```
module MyGem
  class Railtie < Rails::Railtie
    rake_tasks do
      load 'tasks.rake'
    end
  end
end
```

And tasks.rake:

```
task :my_task do
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end
```

I installed the gem (sudo rake install), created an empty rails project and added the gem dependency in the rails' Gemspec (`gem 'my_gem'`). But when I try to run `rake my_task` I get the error `uninitialized constant DatabaseCleaner`.

I've also tried adding `require 'database_cleaner'` from inside the task, which raises the error `no such file to load -- database_cleaner` and `gem 'database_cleaner'` that raises the error `database_cleaner is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.`.

Is there a way to solve this without adding `gem 'database_cleaner'` to the rails project's Gemspec?

Thanks

UPDATE (adding the link to the source code):
https://github.com/jordinl/dummy_tasks

Comment: can you post mygem.gemspec from the gem and the Gemfile.lock from the empty rails app?

Comment: hey! I've added the link to the github repo. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I did to make it work:

tasks.rake

```
require 'database_cleaner'
require 'dummy_tasks'

namespace :db do
  task :dummy => :environment do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    DatabaseCleaner.clean                                             
    Rake::Task['db:seed'].invoke    
  end
end
```

There may be a more elegant way to do this, but this should at least prevent you from having to add the database_cleaner gem to the app Gemfile

Comment: The link is 404 now. Could you please elaborate: what exactly did you do here and why?

Comment: With Rails 6, is the method the same? I have tried what you suggested but it is not working for me; using Rails 6.